# InstallShield Without The Program Files Folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, installshield

I feel like I must be missing something very basic. I have a legacy WinForms application with quite a few projects in it and I need to create an installer for it but I only have VS2012. So I installed InstallShield LE and researched how it all works and the output it gives me is a setup.exe file, setup.ini file, [appname].msi file, and 0x0490.ini file.

It then also has a folder called program files that has all of the files that I specified for a part of the installation and all of this is in the DISK1 folder. That's all fine and great but I've never seen a setup wizard that had a big folder of files sitting next to it, how do I just wrap everything up into one setup wizard without having to have the folder of goods in it?

Comment: It is probably just build litter.  Copy the setup.exe somewhere and check that you can install and uninstall your app with it.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're building a release with the compression turned off.

In the solution explorer tree, expand 'Prepare for Release' and select the 'Releases' node. Find the release you're using in the tree that appears on the left side of the window.

You should see a setting called 'Compression'. If it's set to 'Uncompressed', that's your problem. Change it to Compressed.